# How do I save the tflearn logs into tflearn.model?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tflearn

So basically I forgot to save my model for each training loops. how do I save the /tmp/tflearn_logs/subdir into the model? is there any way to collect it as model like:

```
# Save a model
model.save('my_model.tflearn')
```

from the event logs?

And after that I can automatically load it with:

```
# Load a model
model.load('my_model.tflearn')
```

Here are my event logs:

[image: logs]

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, There's no method to do that. Because logs only save our events data for visualization purpose, while model used for learning model using tflearn. they both working in the opposite way. Solution: Recreate save('.model.tflearn') and run it from 0. :)